# How to determine if the mouse pointer has crossed over an element in javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

It is possible to define a mouseover event for an element so that you know that the mouse pointer is currently somewhere on that element. How to determine if the mousepointer leaves that element area?

Comment: do you want to call some function of java script when the mouse over the element?

Comment: preferably a javascript function that is browser independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you could use `jQuery`. The `mouseover` and `mouseout`events work would work, but I suggest you to use the [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events instead, because the `mouseover`and `mouseout` events **might fire multiple times** if your `element` has children elements.

```
$("#my-element")
    .mousenter(function(){
        console.log('enter');
    })
    .mouseleave(function(){
        console.log('leave');
    });
```

However, if you do not want to use `jQuery`, you could do it in vanilla JS.

```
document.getElementById('my-element').addEventListener('mouseover' function (e) {
    console.log('over');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

[Mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/mouseover) and [mouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/mouseout) and jQuery makes it easy :

```
$("img").mouseover(function(){
   alert('your message');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use onmousemove, onmouseover and onmouseout events...
onmousemove -   The event occurs when the pointer is moving while it is over an element
 
onmouseover -   The event occurs when the pointer is moved onto an element
onmouseout  -   The event occurs when a user moves the mouse pointer out of an element